# Excel : Conditional formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have two columns,

```
    **COL-A**      **COL-B**  
1      419             393
2     2199            1513
3        3               3
4       23              20
5        3               3 
4     2964            2181
```

I want to have conditional formatting using color scales between each `A1 B1`, `A2 B2`, ...

Currently when compared, `419` is green and `393` is red (red-yellow-green).

But the color of column B needs to be based on ratio (`393/419*100`=`93.79%`, which should be closer to green, while `10%` would be closer to be red).

Could you please help me to do this?

Comment: I tried to edit your question to make it easier to understand. Please review my edits to make sure this is what you want.

Comment: @Peter Lang yes.thanx for the formatting

Comment: This would be relatively easy to do in a macro.  Are you okay with using visual basic instead of conditional formatting?

Comment: Using your example, B1 would be closer to green because its ratio is 93.79%. Are you saying that A1 should be closer to red specifically because its cell contains a value representing the remaining 6.21%? Or how exactly is the color of the A cells determined?

Comment: @Evelyn How to do that in vb macros?
@BadNinja Thanks I managed to do that using some cell rules(instead of the colorscales).

Answer (score 2):

I think this does the trick. Conditional format for B2 in the image.

Perhaps a bit late :)

[image]

HTH!